# jQuery each() is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, each

Here is two input fields and I want a functionality that once the user focusout/blur the input field after the entered value that entered value should be converted into the upper case letters.

```
$("#input1").blur(function() {
      $('#input1').val($('#input1').val().toUpperCase());
});
$("#input2").blur(function() {
      $('#input2').val($('#input2').val().toUpperCase());
});
```

If I am using the each() which is working for one input field only. I am writing the code like this.

```
$("#input1,#input2").each(function() {
   $(this).blur(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have syntax error use `$("#input1,#input2").blur(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});`

Answer (score 0):

In the code is missing "});"

Yo can do something like this too:

```js
$("input").each(function() {
   $(this).blur(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
```

If you have more than two input and for example you only want to iterate over two, you can put a class to any input(or any element) that you want to iterate.

```js
$(".example-class").each(function() {
   $(this).blur(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" class="example-class" type="text">
<input id="input3" class="example-class" type="text">
```

Comment: Ohhh... what a mistake I have done.. Thanks for your help. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted is not syntactically correct however if corrected works fine:

```js
$("#input1,#input2").each(function() {
   $(this).blur(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
```

Comment: Happens to everyone, happy to help.